# How do I wait for a value to change?

Tags: java, groovy, parallel-processing

I'm writing a Groovy script which creates a process. I call consumeProcessOutput() to dump the output to a StringBuffer. How can I wait in the main thread without polling?

```
def process = "command".execute()
def builder = new StringBuilder()
process.consumeProcessOutput(builder)
while (!closure.call(builder)) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not wrap your own StringBuilder
and hook the append event

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [waitFor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29)

```
process.waitFor()
```

Or, another possibility would be:

```
def output = 'command'.execute().text
```

Comment: I'm writing an expect-like tool so unfortunately this doesn't work. I'd like to wait until the StringBuffer has changed but the process won't have ended.

Comment: Ahh... You may have problems then...this came up [on the groovy user list](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Any-Tcl-Expect-alternatives-in-Groovy-or-Java-tp4836597p4836813.html) and I think you have to tie in to some other native steam library as Java's is buffered

Comment: Yes I discovered the hard way that the streams are buffered. The Java streams seem to work ok. Last time I tried ExpectJ the output from GDB (in this case) ended up garbled.